# Xcode 9 Beta 2 and Beta 3 Xcode quit unexpectedly while using the libswiftCore.dylib plug-in

Tags: xcode

I downloaded the Xcode 9 Beta 3 today. I attempted to create a new project. The new project template appeared briefly and then the application crashed. I was curious if this was an issue with the new beta and I attempted the same thing on the second beta, which I had not opened or used yet. Same thing.

I am on Sierra 10.12.5 so the betas should work on the operating system. Here is part of the crash log:

```
Process:               Xcode [696]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               9.0 (13158.29)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-13158029000000000~6
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [696]
User ID:               501

PlugIn Path:             /Applications/Xcode-      beta.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
PlugIn Identifier:       libswiftFoundation.dylib
PlugIn Version:          4.0 (900.0.45.6)

Date/Time:             2017-07-10 15:04:10.388 -0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12.5 (16F73)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        B09C3E88-D865-FD5A-D0D0-4B59BB434D0A


Time Awake Since Boot: 99 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: SourceControlAccountManager -      Accounts/Repositories Queue

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 9M137d

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: SourceControlAccountManager - Accounts/Repositories Queue
0   libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x000000010ab2bd5a _T010Foundation3URLV36_unconditionallyBridgeFromObjectiveCACSo5NSURLCSgFZ + 42
1   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000108bc6b1e _T013IDEFoundation31SourceControlFingerprintManagerC08existingD0SSSgSo09DVTSourceC 16RemoteRepositoryC3for_tFTf4gn_n + 46
2   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000108bc5456 _T013IDEFoundation31SourceControlFingerprintManagerC08existingD0SSSgSo09DVTSourceC16RemoteRepositoryC3for_tF + 22
3   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000108b84002 _T013IDEFoundation27SourceControlAccountManagerC31reloadTrustedServerFingerprintsyyFyycfU_Tf4g_n + 386
4   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000108b839b2 _T013IDEFoundation27SourceControlAccountManagerC31reloadTrustedServerFingerprintsyyFyycfU_TA + 34
5   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000108b6c800 _T0Ix_IyB_TR + 32
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffbf8488fc _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffbf849536 _dispatch_barrier_sync_f_invoke + 83
8   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000108b77df7 _T013IDEFoundation27SourceControlAccountManagerC31reloadTrustedServerFingerprintsyyF + 183
9   com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000108bc698d _T013IDEFoundation31SourceControlFingerprintManagerC14loadKnownHostsys10DictionaryVyS2SGSg4from_tFyAH_s5Error_pSgtcfU_yycfU_Tf4gg_n + 237
10  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000108bc6f32 _T013IDEFoundation31SourceControlFingerprintManagerC14loadKnownHostsys10DictionaryVyS2SGSg4from_tFyAH_s5Error_pSgtcfU_yycfU_TA + 50
11  com.apple.dt.IDEFoundation      0x0000000108b6c800 _T0Ix_IyB_TR + 32
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffbf851524 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffbf8488fc _dispatch_client_callout + 8
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffbf855aac _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 925
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffaa114bc9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffaa0d5c0d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffaa0d5114 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
18  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fffa9636ebc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 240
19  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fffa9636cf1 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
20  com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fffa9636b26 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
21  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffa7bcfa54 _DPSNextEvent + 1120
22  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffa834b7ee -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 2796
23  com.apple.dt.DVTKit             0x00000001081239b3 -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 390
24  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffa7bc43db -[NSApplication run] + 926
25  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fffa7b8ee0e NSApplicationMain + 1237
26  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fffbf87e235 start + 1
```

I asked around on Twitter and no one else seems to be having a similar issue. I filed a [Radar](https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=33219643) on this issue. I am working through several pieces of technical materials and being unable to open a project in the Xcode betas is quite inconvenient. I would appreciate any advice about how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

If it's still actual I had the same issue and fixed it removing Xcode cache from:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode.sourcecontrol.Git
```